# Implement Digital Signature in Client /Web Server Architecture

Tags: java, pdf, servlets, itext, digital-signature

I am trying to implement digital signature in web application as example provided by by Bruno Lowagie in White Paper.

4.3.3 Signing a document on the server using a signature created on the client

Pre-signing— the client asks the server for a hash.

Post-signing— the client sends the signed bytes to the server.

every thing is working fine in this example but when we are try to open pdf after signing
it is giving an error **Error during signature verification. Error encountered while validating: Internal cryptographic library error. Error Code: 0x2726**

**Here is my code:**

client:

```
  KeyStore eks = loadKeyStoreFromSmartCard("abc@123");

    // Check if X.509 certification chain is available
    Certificate[] certChain = new X509Certificate[1];
    certChain[0] = getcert_eToken(null, eks);

    String strCertificate  = encodeX509CertChainToBase64(certChain);


    ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(8192);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(byteStream, true);

    String postData = "certChain=" + strCertificate;

    try {

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        URL dataURL = null;

        dataURL = new URL("http://localhost:8085/Digital-Server/PreSignservlet");

        connection = (HttpURLConnection) dataURL.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows 2000)");
        connection.setFollowRedirects(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
        connection.connect();

        out.print(postData);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        byteStream.writeTo(connection.getOutputStream());
        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();


        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int read;
        byte[] data = new byte[256];

        while ((read = in.read(data)) != -1) {
            baos.write(data, 0, read);
        }

        byte[] hash = baos.toByteArray();

        PrivateKey privateKey = getprivate_eToken(null, eks);

        // we sign the bytes received from the server
        Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        sig.initSign(privateKey);
        sig.update(hash);
        data = sig.sign();

        // --------------------------------------------
        connection.disconnect();
        in.close();

        //Calling Post Sign Servelet 
        dataURL = new URL("http://localhost:8085/Digital-Server/PostSignservlet");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) dataURL.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows 2000)");
        connection.setFollowRedirects(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
        connection.connect();
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        byteStream.writeTo(connection.getOutputStream());
        byteStream.write(data);

        in = connection.getInputStream();

        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                "D:\\Digital Signature\\Digital-Server\\WebContent\\WEB-INF\\result\\jaihanuman.pdf");

        // int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[8192];

        while ((read = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }

        System.out.println("Done!");
```

**presign servlet:**

```
      Certificate[] chain = decodeX509CertChainToBase64(cert);

        // we create a reader and a stamper

        ServletContext context = getServletContext();
        String fullPath = context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/result/hello.pdf");

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fullPath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfStamper stamper =  PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, baos, '\0');

        // we create the signature appearance

        PdfSignatureAppearance sap = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
        sap.setReason("Test");
        sap.setLocation("On a server!");
        sap.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(72,737,400,780), 1, "sig");
        sap.setCertificate(chain[0]);

        // we create the signature infrastructure
        PdfSignature dic = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE,PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
        dic.setReason(sap.getReason());
        dic.setLocation(sap.getLocation());
        dic.setContact(sap.getContact());
        dic.setDate(new PdfDate(sap.getSignDate()));
        sap.setCryptoDictionary(dic);

        HashMap<PdfName, Integer> exc = new HashMap<PdfName, Integer>();
        exc.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new Integer(8192 * 2 + 2));
        sap.preClose(exc);

        ExternalDigest externaldigest =new ExternalDigest() {

        public MessageDigest getMessageDigest(String hashAlgorithm)
                throws GeneralSecurityException {
            return DigestAlgorithms.getMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm, null);
        }
    };

    PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, "SHA256", null, externaldigest, false);
    InputStream data = sap.getRangeStream();

    byte hash[] = DigestAlgorithms.digest(data, externaldigest.getMessageDigest("SHA256"));
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    byte[] sh = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, cal, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);

    // We store the objects we'll need for post signing in a session
    HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute("sgn", sgn);
    session.setAttribute("hash", hash);
    session.setAttribute("cal", cal);
    session.setAttribute("sap", sap);
    session.setAttribute("baos", baos);


    // we write the hash that needs to be signed to the HttpResponse output
    OutputStream os = resp.getOutputStream();
    os.write(sh, 0, sh.length);
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("end of pre sign servelet---------------");
```

**post sign servlet:**

```
        try
        {
        // we get the objects we need for postsigning from the session
        System.out.println("call post servelet1");
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);

        PdfPKCS7 sgn = (PdfPKCS7)session.getAttribute("sgn");
        byte[] hash = (byte[])session.getAttribute("hash");
        Calendar cal = (Calendar)session.getAttribute("cal");
        PdfSignatureAppearance sap =(PdfSignatureAppearance) session.getAttribute("sap");
        ByteArrayOutputStream os =(ByteArrayOutputStream) session.getAttribute("baos");
        session.invalidate();

        // we read the signed bytes

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        InputStream is = req.getInputStream();

        int read;
        byte[] data = new byte[256];
        while ((read = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
        baos.write(data, 0, read);
        }
        // we complete the PDF signing process

        sgn.setExternalDigest(baos.toByteArray(), null, "RSA");
        byte[] encodedSig = sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(hash, cal, null, null, null, CryptoStandard.CADES);
        byte[] paddedSig = new byte[8192];
        System.arraycopy(encodedSig, 0, paddedSig, 0, encodedSig.length);
        PdfDictionary dic2 = new PdfDictionary();
        dic2.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(paddedSig).setHexWriting(true));
        sap.close(dic2);

        // we write the signed document to the HttpResponse output stream

        // let's write the file in memory to a file anyway
        ServletContext context = getServletContext();
        String fullPath = context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/result/sign.pdf");

        byte[] pdf = os.toByteArray();
        OutputStream sos = resp.getOutputStream();
        sos.write(pdf, 0, pdf.length);
        sos.flush();
        sos.close();

        /*OutputStream sos = new FileOutputStream(fullPath);
        os.writeTo(sos);
        sos.flush();
        sos.close();*/

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("call post servelet2");
```

Here I am doing one extra thing, I am encoding certificate chain to  **base64** before sending
to presign servlet.

Comment: Please share a sample pdf signed by your setup.

Comment: link for pdf is :https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=449a4623ebec694c&id=449A4623EBEC694C%21114

Comment: Ok, the CMS signature container SignerInfo contains a "signature" value which looks like this "certChain=MIIDKT...". This obviously is not a signature value. I'll look at your code later, but obviously there are two issues: 1. You put the certificate chain where you have to put a signature and 2. you use base64 encoding where unencoded data are needed.

Comment: thanks for suggesting..

Comment: @Anuj Can you elaborate what was the code in loadKeyStoreFromSmartCard() ? I'm trying to fetch the certificate from a device like USB or Smart Card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is somewhat confusing:

The client code retrieves a signer-certificate-only certificate chain in `certChain`,  base64-encodes it into `strCertificate`, prefixes it with "certChain=" and puts that string into `postData`. Then it opens a connection to the `PreSignservlet` and sends the data to post in a complicated way using an intermediary `ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream` (why don't you simply write `postData.getBytes()` to the `connection.getOutputStream()`).

Unfortunately you neither close the output stream nor add a content length header. Thus, the servlet might have difficulties recognizing the end-of-input. But that does not seem to be a current issue here.

Now you take the data returned by the servlet as is (i.e. without decoding) and feed it into signature creation. Then you open a connection to the `PostSignservlet` to send the signature bytes to.

So far it makes sense.

*But instead of the signature data you now send the information you already had sent before (the encoded certificate) to that servlet and afterwards add the signature to the local `byteStream`!*

Why don't you simply write the signature in `data` to `connection.getOutputStream()`?

Eventually you retrieve the output of the servlet as result PDF.

Your writing the certificate instead of the actual signature to the `PostSignservlet` would explain why the CMS signature container SignerInfo in the result PDF contains a "signature" value which looks like this "certChain=MIIDKT...", i.e. like your base64 encoded certificate.

Comment: ok i am trying to modified code suggested by you. mean while i want to know how  can we send certificate from eToken to java servlet without encoding to base 64.is there any other way..

Comment: You know how to transfer byte arrays. Thus, simply send `getcert_eToken(null, eks).getEncoded()` and in the servlet use `CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(inStream)` to get a `Certificate` instance again.

Comment: thnx.gr8 it is my first post and i have never thought i will get response so early..

Comment: after implementing your suggestion.Now cryptography library error. Error Code: 0x2726 is gone.but now it is showing message The document has been altered or corrupted since the signature was applied.and no icon was displaying on sign pdf even signature invalid cross icon. when i have seen pdf metadata there so many 0000000 like numbers in to that..so what is the reason for this?

Comment: modified pdf:https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=449A4623EBEC694C!269&app=WordPdf&wdo=2

Comment: one thing also i am not getting is that we return array of = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, cal, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS); for signing,as you said earlier that you are fedding data for signing without decoding,what does it mean?Can you explain..

Comment: I'll look into that tomorrow.

Comment: Your signer certificate does not conform to the RFCs involved. Both [RFC 5280](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.2) and the older [RFC 3280](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3280#section-4.1.2.2) (which is referenced from the [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)) require **The serial number MUST be a positive integer**, but in your case the serial number is `-4840095856524324050` which is clearly negative. My tools, therefore, reject the signature. I don't know whether Adobe Reader also is unhappy about that fact.

Comment: *no icon was displaying on sign pdf* - The icon on the PDF itself is not how Adobe currently prefers to represent signature validity; instead you get the information in the ribbon and in the signature window.

Comment: *as you said earlier that you are fedding data for signing without decoding,what does it mean?Can you explain* - well, when going through your client code I saw that you base64 encoded your parameter but used the returned data as is, i.e. without any decoding. That is a confusing interface design but seems to match what your servlet expects and returns.

Comment: *i have seen pdf metadata there so many 0000000 like numbers in to that* - You reserved 8 KB for the signature but your signature is only 1318 bytes in size. The remainder is filled with '0'.

Comment: so please suggest what should i have to do.. and after  using this approach for sending certficte to server getcert_eToken(null, eks).getEncoded() and in the servlet use CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(inStream)

Comment: *please suggest what should i have to do* - first of all get a signing device with a RFC conforming certificate. In the meantime you can test using soft tokens.